# iOS: Why doesn't UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable always notify?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm writing an ios native module (for react native) that detects when protected data is unavailable and available. I'm listening on `UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable` and `UIApplicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable.`

My test iphone has a passcode, so this should correspond to when the device is locked & unlocked. In other words, `UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable` fires sometimes but not most times I lock my device.

I've noticed that I reliably get notified when the device is **unlocked**, but often **don't** get notified when the device is **locked**.

Why could that be? I've pasted a snippet of my code below. I'm testing on a real iphone, not on the iOS simulator.

```
- (void)startObserving
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceLocked) name:UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable object:nil];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceUnlocked) name:UIApplicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable object:nil];
}


- (void)deviceLocked
{
  /* this log line usually does not show up when i lock my iphone */
  NSLog(@"** DATAP: Device is locked"); 
}

- (void)deviceUnlocked
{
  /* this log line always shows up when i unlock my iphone */
  NSLog(@"** DATAP: Device is unlocked");
}
```

Comment: My guess is: when u lock device, ur device goes to sleep so does ur app.

Comment: thanks for the insight @GeneCode, any ideas on what I could try to get around this?